# DRF How to retrieve auth user info?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Now I can just get info by id. -> `user/{id}`
I want to retrieve self auth user and get his information by default like `user`

**My view**

```
class UserInfoViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                           viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.UserFollowersSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(privacy__is_public=True)
```

Comment: do you want to use the same endpoint(`user/{id}`)? if not, please share the URL pattern you want for the user info API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to get information about the currently logged in user you could do something like this this:

```
@action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
def current_user(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Without an additional action, I could think of the following possibilities.

(1) You could overwrite your `get_queryset` method to just filter for `user=self.request.user`.

(2) You could overwrite `get_object` to return `self.request.user`.

Comment: If it possible to get information about the currently logged in user  without action?

Comment: @kate I just edited my answer. Did you think of something like this?